# Configuring Quercus on Google App Engine

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, quercus

I am currently working with GAE and was trying to figure out if there was some way that I can run php on GAE. Fortunately, I came across [Quercus](http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus_Google_App_Engine) and was very happy to find that it had all that i needed.

But the problem now is that once I include the resin.jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder and try to update app using the google plugin in eclipse, it gives me an error saying that the size of the jar file is big and recommends me adding `--enable_jar_splitting` flag.

Now I have gone through a lot of sites where people have had similar problems. So what do I do to overcome this?

So here's what I am looking for in short:
1. Either a way to include this flag in the eclipse plugin
2. Finding out a way to split the jar file.

SOLUTION:

The only way that the above is currently possible is by using the command line utility present in the sdk/bin folder called - appcfg.sh

`appcfg.sh --enable_jar_splitting -e user@domain.com update /path/to/war/file`

PS: It is assumed that you have added the path to the bin folder as a environmental variable.

Comment: Please see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2552#c12 and http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2552#c14

Comment: Ah! I had actually seen the first one. And yes, this works - bin/appcfg.cmd --enable_jar_splitting -e user@example.org update c:/path/to/project/war/. Pity it isn't included in the plugin by default. Thanks though!

Comment: Let me know if I should add it as an answer or better add an answer your own with a little bit of description.

Comment: I will append an answer to my question. I have one more doubt before that one. I tried running a sample php file on my developement server and it worked. But when I tried doing the same online, it told me some server error and later gave me the following error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.caucho.util.Alarm**. Do you know what can be the possible reason?